# Extjs Roweditor Click on update

Tags: extjs

I am new to Extjs,I am working on Extjs3.2 grid RowEditor. I want Once we click on **Add Employee** Button editor windows pops up and when we click on cancel editor gots close but row get added to the grid .I want if we click on cancel it get back to initial state without new row

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/row-editing.html

How to Stop This??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a 'canceledit' listener for RowEditing plugin and write logic acceptable for you.

For example I have written:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        canceledit: function(editor, context) {
            if(context.rowIdx == 0 && context.value == "New Guy") {
                store.remove(context.record);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Working Demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/3Ht5u/2/`

Comment: Also you can add 'beforeedit' listener and save rows user has saved. On cancel you can check if row is not saved by user you can remove it. Do not forget in this case mark all initial rows user saved.

Comment: thanks i am doing like this... did you find any issue  canceledit: function(grid,rowIndex,e) {
     
        editor.stopEditing();
     var rec = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
     alert(rec.get("id"))
       
         store.remove(rec);
           }

Comment: I did't find any issues on this code. But it will remove any record you try to edit and press cancel.

Comment: Was this solution helpful for you? Do you have other questions? Please feel free to comment. And do not forget to mark this answere as accepted :)